# Running a epson Scanner perfection 3170

Tags: 11.04, scanning, epson

How can I make my scanner **Epson perfection 3170** running under ubuntu 11.04 ?

When I run "Simple Scan" it said:"No scanner detected".

[image]

Thanks

**Edit**:

after I saw suli8's anwser. I downloaded both rpm:iscan-plugin-gt-9400-1.0.0-1.c2.i386.rpm and iscan-2.10.0-1.c2.i386.rpm

both where transformed+installed with alien. I tried it twice.

```
$ sudo alien -i iscan_2.10.0-2_i386.deb
Warning: Skipping conversion of scripts in package iscan: postinst postrm
Warning: Use the --scripts parameter to include the scripts.
    dpkg --no-force-overwrite -i iscan_2.10.0-2_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 160709 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace iscan 2.10.0-2 (using iscan_2.10.0-2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement iscan ...
Setting up iscan (2.10.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

$ sudo alien -i iscan-plugin-gt-9400_1.0.0-2_i386.deb 
Warning: Skipping conversion of scripts in package iscan-plugin-gt-9400: postinst postrm
Warning: Use the --scripts parameter to include the scripts.
    dpkg --no-force-overwrite -i iscan-plugin-gt-9400_1.0.0-2_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 160709 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace iscan-plugin-gt-9400 1.0.0-2 (using iscan-plugin-gt-9400_1.0.0-2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement iscan-plugin-gt-9400 ...
Setting up iscan-plugin-gt-9400 (1.0.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

After rebooting. "Simple Scan" still says: "No scanner detected".

**edit2**

```
$ sudo dpkg -i iscan_2.10.0-2_i386.deb 
[sudo] password for lindenb: 
(Reading database ... 160709 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace iscan 2.10.0-2 (using iscan_2.10.0-2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement iscan ...
Setting up iscan (2.10.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place


$sudo dpkg -i iscan-plugin-gt-9400_1.0.0-2_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 160709 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace iscan-plugin-gt-9400 1.0.0-2 (using iscan-plugin-gt-9400_1.0.0-2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement iscan-plugin-gt-9400 ...
Setting up iscan-plugin-gt-9400 (1.0.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

**edit3**
as a note I'm copying here the original Ronok's response  at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1028064&page=2

1) first see where things stand Is the Scanner USB properly connected to the computer ?

```
lsusb



Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04b8:0116 Seiko Epson Corp. Perfection 3170 (GT-9400)
```

2) Check that SANE & XSANE are Present:

```
sudo apt-get install sane &&
sudo apt-get install libsane &&
sudo apt-get install libsane-extras &&
sudo apt-get install sane-utils &&
sudo apt-get install xsane &&
sudo apt-get install xsane-common &&
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5
```

3) Check That the system is upto date: System > Administration > Update Manager (or)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

4) Then lets see where things stand:

```
xsane
```

Get a Pop up Window:

> No Devices available

5)
To get a list of devices

```
scanimage -L
```

> No scanners were identified. If you
>   were expecting something different,
>   check that the scanner is plugged in,
>   turned on and detected by the
>   sane-find-scanner tool (if
>   appropriate). Please read the
>   documentation which came with this
>   software (README, FAQ, manpages).

6) See if SANE can see the Scanner ?

```
sane-find-scanner
```

> found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8,
>   product=0x0116) at libusb:001:007

7) open and maybe edit this file Check to see that "epson" & epson2" are uncommented (that is with out"#")

```
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/dll.conf
```

8)(with Epson issues all roads seem to lead here) so Go to:
http://www.avasys.jp/lx-bin2/linux_e/scan/DL1.do
Fill in the form and download:
---> iscan-2.10.0-1.c2.i386.rpm
---> iscan-plugin-gt-9400-1.0.0-1.c2.i386.rpm
to the Desktop
thats your:

```
cd ~/Desktop && pwd
```

9)Get Alien
Alien allows you to convert ".rpm" files into Debian ".deb" packages, which can be installed with dpkg.

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

10)Make the ".deb" file from the ".rpm" file (Note in the code-example the "*" takes the place of e.g: "-plugin-gt-9400-1.0.0-1.c2.i386"

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo alien -d iscan*.rpm
sudo dpkg -i iscan*.deb
```

11)Edit the libsane-extras.rules

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/50-libsane-extras.rules
```

12)if it is empty add this line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04b8", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0116", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner"
13)
```

Edit the epson.conf

```
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epson.conf
```

14) add this line (the USB device ID from step #1 above) at the end:

```
usb 0x04b8 0x0116
```

15)Add yourself to the scanner group (adding the scanner group if needed)

System > Administration > Users and Groups > manage groups > unlock > add > check self

16) Do a complete Shutdown & restart the machine

17) Try To get a list of devices again

```
scanimage -L
```

> device `epson:libusb:001:006' is a
>   Epson flatbed scanner

18)

```
iscan
```

Comment: it would probably be best if you split off the solution part from the bottom and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://www.avasys.jp/lx-bin2/linux_e/scan/DL1.do) you can find the driver for your scanner. i did check it and it is available as .rpm package or as a tar.gz source.
i suggest you grab the .rpm package and convert it to .deb using [alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto) and then install it. it should work with driver installed.

Comment: did you convert it succesfully? if yes, try to double click the deb file. according to the wiki the command to run when you have already .deb is " sudo dpkg -i package_file.deb "

Comment: Thanks again. I copy+pasted the output of the commands. Nothing happened. In gimp: menu Filters/Aquire_Image/Scanning(iscan) remains disabled.

Comment: ok, please see this  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1052521&page=2    mmm you can try that out, and check the last comment there with the usb-3.0 thing...

Comment: and see this also.. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1028064&page=2

Comment: great! what exactly did do the fix? can you describe here for future users. thx

Answer (score 0):

let works ubuntu 11.10 with epson scanner [resolved]!

http://mancioboxblog.altervista.org/?p=315

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: It would be especially helpful for the essential information to be included here, because the linked page is not in English, and thus will likely not be accessible to many users of our site.