# Running a Epson Scanner Perfection 3170 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, scanner, epson

This is the same problem I had for Ubuntu 11.04: [Running a epson Scanner perfection 3170](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49389) but I cannot apply it for Ubuntu 14.04.

I installed both  `iscan_2.10.0-2_i386.deb` & `iscan-plugin-gt-9400_1.0.0-2_i386.deb`

```
$ sudo sane-find-scanner  | grep -i epson
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0116 [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:002:003

$ sudo scanimage -L
device `epson:libusb:002:003' is a Epson �   flatbed scanner

$ tail /etc/sane.d/epson.conf 
usb 0x04b8 0x0116

$ sudo sane-find-scanner  | grep -i epson
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0116 [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:002:003

$ head /etc/udev/rules.d/50-libsane-extras.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04b8", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0116", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner"

$ groups lindenb
lindenb : lindenb adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin saned sambashare scanner
```

`iscan`: (could not send command to scanner)

`sudo iscan`: (could not send command to scanner)

Do you know how to fix this please?

**EDIT:** Cross posted at: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2252458

**EDIT2:** Here is the iscan trace:

```
$ sudo SANE_DEBUG_EPSON=255  iscan
[sanei_debug] Setting debug level of epson to 255.
[epson] sane_init: sane-backends 1.0.23
[epson] sane_init, ># epson.conf<
[epson] sane_init, >#<
[epson] sane_init, ># here are some examples for how to configure the EPSON backend<
[epson] sane_init, >#<
[epson] sane_init, ># SCSI scanner:<
[epson] sane_init, >scsi EPSON<
[epson] sane_init, ># for the GT-6500:<
[epson] sane_init, >scsi "EPSON SC"<
[epson] sane_init, >#<
[epson] sane_init, ># Parallel port scanner:<
[epson] sane_init, >#pio 0x278<
[epson] sane_init, >#pio 0x378<
[epson] sane_init, >#pio 0x3BC<
[epson] sane_init, >#<
[epson] sane_init, ># USB scanner:<
[epson] sane_init, ># There are two different methods of configuring a USB scanner: libusb and the kernel module<
[epson] sane_init, ># For any system with libusb support (which is pretty much any recent Linux distribution) the<
[epson] sane_init, ># following line is sufficient. This however assumes that the connected scanner (or to be more<
[epson] sane_init, ># accurate, it's device ID) is known to the backend.<
[epson] sane_init, >usb<
[epson] attach_one_usb()
[epson] SANE Epson Backend v0.2.47 - 2006-08-21
[epson] attach(, 3)
[epson] attach: opening 
[epson] sane_init, ># For libusb support for unknown scanners use the following command<
[epson] sane_init, ># usb <product ID> <device ID><
[epson] sane_init, ># e.g.:<
[epson] sane_init, ># usb 0x4b8 0x110<
[epson] sane_init, ># And for the scanner module, use the following configuration:<
[epson] sane_init, >#usb /dev/usbscanner0<
[epson] sane_init, >#usb /dev/usb/scanner0<
[epson] sane_init, >usb 0x04b8 0x0116<
[epson] attach_one_usb(libusb:002:002)
[epson] SANE Epson Backend v0.2.47 - 2006-08-21
[epson] attach(libusb:002:002, 3)
[epson] attach: opening libusb:002:002
[epson] Found valid EPSON scanner: 0x4b8/0x116 (vendorID/productID)
[epson] reset()
[epson] send buf, size = 2
[epson] buf[0] 1b .
[epson] buf[1] 40 @
[epson] w_cmd_count = 1
[epson] r_cmd_count = 0
[epson] w_cmd_count = 1
[epson] r_cmd_count = 1
[epson] receive buf, expected = 1, got = 1
[epson] buf[0] 15 .
[epson] get_identity_information()
[epson] send buf, size = 2
[epson] buf[0] 1b .
[epson] buf[1] 49 I
[epson] w_cmd_count = 2
[epson] r_cmd_count = 1
[epson] w_cmd_count = 2
[epson] r_cmd_count = 2
[epson] receive buf, expected = 4, got = 1
[epson] buf[0] 15 .
[epson] code   15
[epson] type     0x01
[epson] level    0x00
[epson] no option equipment installed
[epson] Unknown type  or level , using B3
[epson] fbf tlx 0.000000 tly 0.000000 brx 0.000000 bry 0.000000 [mm]
[epson] send buf, size = 2
[epson] buf[0] 1b .
[epson] buf[1] 44 D
[epson] w_cmd_count = 3
[epson] r_cmd_count = 2
[epson] w_cmd_count = 3
[epson] r_cmd_count = 3
[epson] receive buf, expected = 1, got = 1
[epson] buf[0] 15 .
[epson] send buf, size = 2
[epson] buf[0] 1b .
[epson] buf[1] 44 D
[epson] w_cmd_count = 4
[epson] r_cmd_count = 3
[epson] w_cmd_count = 4
[epson] r_cmd_count = 4
[epson] receive buf, expected = 1, got = 1
[epson] buf[0] 15 .
[epson] send buf, size = 2
[epson] buf[0] 1b .
[epson] buf[1] 44 D
[epson] w_cmd_count = 5
[epson] r_cmd_count = 4
[epson] w_cmd_count = 5
[epson] r_cmd_count = 5
[epson] receive buf, expected = 1, got = 1
[epson] buf[0] 15 .
[epson] Max. supported color depth = 8
[epson] request_focus_position()
[epson] Disabling 'Set Focus' support
[epson] send buf, size = 2
[epson] buf[0] 1b .
[epson] buf[1] 66 f
[epson] w_cmd_count = 6
[epson] r_cmd_count = 5
[epson] w_cmd_count = 6
[epson] r_cmd_count = 6
[epson] receive buf, expected = 4, got = 1
[epson] buf[0] 15 .
[epson] code   15
[epson] scanner model: 
[epson] close_scanner(fd = 0)
[epson] w_cmd_count = 6
[epson] r_cmd_count = 6
[epson] w_cmd_count = 6
[epson] r_cmd_count = 6
[epson] sane_get_devices()
(end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete thread at: http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/sane-devel/2014-November/032869.html

What I've done:

1. Uninstall the sane/xsane/... packages installed by Ubuntu
2. Clone sane-backend from git & install it

   ```
   ./configure --enable-libusb_1_0  --disable-translations --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc
   ```
3. Clone sane-frontend  from git & install it

   ```
   ./configure  --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc
   ```
4. Edit `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` : Comment out `epson` and `epson scan`. Add `epkowa` that was missing in this file.
5. The file `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` was missing . I've added the `usb-id` for my scanner.

   ```
   $ grep -vE '^#' /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf 

   scsi EPSON    
   usb    
   usb 0x04b8 0x0116
   ```
6. Install iscan and its plugin from the RPM available at Epson
7. Reboot

Comment: The debs available from Epson are a little easier to install than RPMs.

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar problems with an Epson Perfection 3170 and Ubuntu 12.04. I tried all the `sane.d`, epkowa, udev rules but didn't want to use the git clone, so I tried using Rolf Bensch's PPA `ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git`, still no success.

I recalled seeing an earlier error message about missing `libjpeg62`; after installing it, xsane worked!